# Camera rotate through touch drag

Tags: unity-game-engine

Camera rotate through touch drag.

I want to rotate the camera using a touch drag.

So I saw many scripts through Google search.

Touch often looks at strange camera.

Let me know what the problem is.

It's what I'm testing.

```
void Start()
{
    xAngle = 0f;
    yAngle = 5f;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0);
}

void Update()
{

    if (isCanRotate != false)
    {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                FirstPoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                xAngleTemp = xAngle;
                yAngleTemp = yAngle;
            }
            else if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                SecondPoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                xAngle = xAngleTemp + (SecondPoint.x - FirstPoint.x) * 360f / Screen.width;
                yAngle = yAngleTemp - (SecondPoint.y - FirstPoint.y) * 360f / Screen.height;


                if (yAngle < -60f)
                    yAngle = -60f;
                if (yAngle > 80f)
                    yAngle = 80f;

                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I just checked and there's no problem if you build and test Android. But I build and test with WebGL and the screen turns on in WebGl.

Is there a solution in WebGl?

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated one:
(Note: I removed your boolean variable because I am not sure when you are enabling it)

```
    Vector3 FirstPoint;
    Vector3 SecondPoint;
    float xAngle;
    float yAngle;
    float xAngleTemp;
    float yAngleTemp;

    void Start()
    {
        xAngle = 0;
        yAngle = 0;
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                FirstPoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                xAngleTemp = xAngle;
                yAngleTemp = yAngle;
            }
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                SecondPoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                xAngle = xAngleTemp + (SecondPoint.x - FirstPoint.x) * 180 / Screen.width;
                yAngle = yAngleTemp + (SecondPoint.y - FirstPoint.y) * 90 / Screen.height;
                this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is still a problem of looking at strange camera from time to time when you touch.

After touch, the camera should see the original viewing position and move during drag.

As soon as you touch it, the camera sees the opposite direction or something strange.

Is it an initialization problem?

Comment: I just checked and there's no problem if you build and test Android.

But I build and test with WebGL and the screen turns on in WebGl.